# How to parse XML in objective c

Tags: iphone

Hello i want to parse xml.Please help me.Here is my node

```
    <RadioButton id="1" name="Gender">

        <Item>Male</Item>
        <Item>Female</Item>

    </RadioButton>
```

i want to parse and i want to create comma separated string

Comment: You could use NSXMLParser (have a look at the documentation) or one of the various XML parsing libraries out there, such as TouchXML or KissXML.

Comment: If you don't care enough to accept an answer why do you expect someone to care enough to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here are releated the SO post,

[Parser XML with NSXMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209860/parser-xml-with-nsxmlparser)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

[NSXMLParser example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example)

below is the blog tutorial for using `NSXMLParser`.

http://markstruzinski.com/?p=47

Answer (score 0):

http://sivatechranti.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/parsing-xml-on-iphone/

easy to explain

anonter site very useful

http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/TouchXML-Download-47225.html

direct download...and see this project and implemant in yr project and drag in your project and use directly.....